# Rails model structure to support objects with varying number of fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design

Im wondering how to best go about structuring some Rails models so that they could support a varying number of input fields.

Let's say that I have an article model that belongs_to a theme model. I want to have any number of themes and I want to allow each theme to define it's own fields. For example, theme_1 might define primary_colour and theme_2 might define colour_1, colour_2 and font.

Essentially the choice of theme determines what additional information needs to be collected for the article to be able to properly apply the theme.

If article_1 is using theme_1 then I need to store a primary_color value for whenever I render article_1. If article_2 is also using theme_1 I want to be able to define a different primary_color value. Similarly, if article_3 uses theme_2 then I'll need to store color_1, color_2 and font.

The themes define the required fields, the values that are required would be unique to the article.

So far I have come up with the following but Im not confident its the best solution:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :theme
  has_many :article_details
end

class Theme < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :fields
end

class ArticleDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :field
  belongs_to :listing
end
```

The article has a theme and a theme has fields so I know what fields I need to populate for the article. Articles also have article_details where I store a value and a reference to the field that the value is for.

I hope I've made the description clear. Any feedback is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: There are many ways to approach this.  The best choice depends primarily on:
1. How many themes you envision having
2. How you plan on accessing or updating your themes (specifically, do you need to find all articles with primary color of blue, or given an article, do you just need to figure out what its theme is?)

Comment: @Julie - For the sake of argument, let's say 5-15 themes but I wanted to break things apart so as to not limit theme flexibility. I don't foresee trying to find all articles with primary color blue. I want to be able to easily 'apply' the theme. So if article_1 has primary_color blue, I might have css for theme_1 where I'd want to specify a primary_color variable.

Answer (score 0):

Given there are more than a handful of potential themes and that you do not plan to do queries updates based on the fields required, I'd recommend using a hashed column.  So something like this:

`class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Columns on the articles table include:
  # Indexed string called 'theme'
  # text column (not string!) called 'fields'
  serialize :fields

end`

Then you will be able to do something like:

`a = Article.new
a.fields = {color1: 'blue', color2: 'red', fontFamily: 'Verdana'}
a.save`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I go with this route I would be limiting my ability to query the fields should the need arise.

Im wondering if I could set the themes up as a polymorphic association on the articles. Article has_one theme through ArticleTheme or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

I think I was over-thinking this solution. If Article has a polymorphic association on Theme then I could define n themes each with our own set of fields:

```
class CreateArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :articles do |t|
      t.references :theme, polymorphic: true, index: true
    end
  end
end

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :theme, polymorphic: true
end

class MyTheme < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :article
end
```

At this point if, `MyTheme` defines `primary_color` I can do something like this:

```
article = Article.new
article.theme = MyTheme.new(primary_color: 'blue')
article.save
article.theme.primary_color
 => 'blue'
```

Which for the time being anyways, satisfies what I was looking for.